# Code is not Pasting the Value on above rows which are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a code which copy and paste the data into table.

Now issue is that when code paste the data it starts from end of the table not from 2nd ROW

here is my code.

```
        sh5.Range("B6:C6").Value = sh4.Range("AF10:AG10").Value
         lastR = sh6.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 sh6.Range("G" & lastR).Resize(1, 2).Value = sh5.Range("B6:C6").Value
```

It should paste the data from ROW 2 beacuse it is empty.

Any help over this problem will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your problem lies with `lastR = sh6.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. Because it is a table object, that method will stop at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Thank you for the response how to fix that problem.

Comment: One more End(xlUp) should so the trick.  `lastR = sh6.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: I used your way @Axuary but it stops adding the further data in row 3, 4,5 and so on, until stop pressing the run button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a table things go differently... Please, try the next approach:

```
Sub testLastEmptyRTable()
  Dim sh5 As Worksheet, sh6 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngLst As Range
  
  Set sh5 = Worksheets("Sheet5")
  Set sh6 = Worksheets("Sheet6")
  Set rngLst = sh6.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange 'if you have more then one table, use its name
  lastR = rngLst.cells(rngLst.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1

  sh6.Range("G" & lastR).Resize(1, 2).Value = sh5.Range("B6:C6").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: FaneDuru, Thank you for the answer but how to add Range? in the code where data will be pasted

Comment: Alright, but i tried to make changes according to sheet where data will be pasted it is not working?

Comment: i have tried to make changes but always an error occurrs

Comment: @Learning: Now, I am at home. Your way of copying looks correct. Do you receive an error when try doing it? If not, please check what do you have in sh5.Range("B6:C6").Value. Maybe the range is empty...

Comment: No i do not receive any error it is really difficult to for me to add range in your code? it has sh5.Range("B6:C6") two values which will paste in sh6 g2 and f2

Comment: @Learning: Try please, inserting this line before the one when the code tries copying: `Debug.Print sh5.Range("B6"), sh5.Range("C6"): Stop`. The code will stop on this line. What does it return in Immediate Window (being in VBE press `Ctrl + G`)? And the code as you have it will paste in the range "G:H"...

Comment: I am trying to saying you that that above code you have posted is without any range. First i have to add the ranges for both sheets where from data will be copied and where data will be pasted. So i would request you first please update the ranges in the code i have tried to add and updated my result in post please have alook.

Comment: @Learning:  Of course, I did not do that. I did not care about such a simple issue... I only tried showing you how to determine the last row in a table... How to know which are your appropriate used sheets? It is a generic code working on the active sheet. If you would declare you sheets and set them, I could see what they refer. Otherwise, how  could I know what sheets are they referring? Should I deduce that `sh5` refers "Sheet5" sheet, `sh6` refers "Sheet6"?

Comment: @Learning: I updated the above code trying to guess. But this is not a way to write code... I thought that such customization is something simple to be done by yourself. Otherwise, your learning process will take more than necessary... :)

Comment: @Learning: Did I guess the involved sheets references? Does the code work now as you need? Besides all that, in order to avoid such problems, please put `Option Explicit` on top of all your modules. This will warn you when a variable is not declared...

Comment: your guess is always helpful. You are really great itis working fine now

Comment: @Learning: Glad I could help!. But I think it's time to dare more... :)

Comment: Sure i am up. @FaneDuru